# error while publishing package - "name" is invalid for new packages

Tags: yarnpkg

I'm trying to publish a package but gets: error Couldn't publish package:

> https://registry.yarnpkg.com/CreatorFramework: \"CreatorFramework\" is
>   invalid for new packages

Same result if the package name is Creator

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This error is coming because the npm pkg name can't contain the **UPPERCASE** Letters. I was also getting the same error when I was using the **UPPERCASE** in pkg name like here **apphttpRequest**.
[image]

When I changed from **apphttpRequest** to all **LOWERCASE** characters i.e. **app-http-request**, it got successfully published.
[image]